# jQuery losing reference to Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a form that is submitted via ajax and is then updated by the response.

Before the submit takes place I execute the following code which works the first time but after that on the second submit, the code does not execute.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.edit_customer').submit(function(event) {
    console.log("test");
    if(document.getElementById("sameAsBilling").checked == true){
        $("#customer_addresses_attributes_1_line_1").val($("#customer_addresses_attributes_0_line_1").val());
        $("#customer_addresses_attributes_1_line_2").val($("#customer_addresses_attributes_0_line_2").val());
        $("#customer_addresses_attributes_1_city").val($("#customer_addresses_attributes_0_city").val());
        $("#customer_addresses_attributes_1_state").val($("#customer_addresses_attributes_0_state").val());
        $("#customer_addresses_attributes_1_zip_code").val($("#customer_addresses_attributes_0_zip_code").val());

    }
});
});
```

I've also tried changing the listener to this:

```
$(document).on("submit", ".edit_customer", function(){ console.log("test");});
```

This code doesn't execute at all.

One thing to note is I am using Ruby on Rails which uses Rails UJS. I'm not sure why the second line of code isn't solving the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I have another element in my form that I use to fire JS using the same type of code and it works fine everytime. Here is the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#qb-customers-btn', function(){
    //code here makes an ajax call and loads in data
});


<span class="input-group-text bg-success text-light" id="qb-customers-btn">Load</span>
```

Update:

I ended up abandoning this and just used a button click listener, but now I am back with the same exact problem on a different form on a different page. I've tried everything I can think of. The only thing that works at the moment is wrapping the listener in an `init` function, calling `init` on document.load and then calling `init` again after the ajax has erased and reloaded the form on the page.

Comment: If the delegate event handler is not catching it at all, that would suggest the event is being cancelled before it can propagate out to the document level.  Which would make sense, since you said you are doing an ajax update, rather than a form submit.

Comment: I don't know. Unfortunately the `rails-ujs` library is actually submitting the form and I don't have much control over that. I do know however that it is indeed being submitted to the server successfully every time I attempt a form submit. I also get a successful response.  @Taplar

Comment: is it possible that after your first successful submit, the DOM gets updated eg `.edit_customer` no longer exists?you can control the DOM before and after submitting with rails-ujs

Comment: @kasperite I have checked that too and it's not the case.

Comment: Why are you even using plain javascript regarding `getElementById` in the if statement, when you have jQuery at your disposal?

Comment: @CannonMoyer do you use turbolinks in your app ?

Comment: @Vishal No I am not.